# Select a value in Drop down box using protractor

Tags: automation, protractor

I'm learning protractor and i came across with an issue selecting a given value from an Autocomplete.
How can i click a given string which has following source code using the protractor

[image]

I'm practicing in the following URL: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#option-groups

Comment: could you be more specific. Have you already tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor is only able to interact with elements present in the DOM of the page. The elements for the underlying state options will not be loaded into the DOM until the input box for the State Group has been interacted with. 
You can select the Maine option as follows:

**app.js**

```
describe('desribe the test', () => {
    it('the it', async () => {

        await browser.get('https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#option-groups');

        let statesGroupField = element(by.xpath('//input[@placeholder="States Group"]'));
        await statesGroupField.click();
        let maineDropdownOption = element(by.xpath('//span[text()="Maine"]'));
        await maineDropdownOption.click();

        await browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    })
})
```